# Getting the undeclared of identifiers in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a written the code in table view controller for displaying the data in table view, but I am getting error that not declared identifier.
I am attaching screen shot.
[image]

Comment: you said that u had attached the screen shot , but there is not image here

Comment: Please add your code instead of a screenshot. Also post the error showing the line where it occurred.

Comment: Now see the screen shot @Purushothaman

Comment: why are u giving screen shot , rather u can paste the code in the pastie.org

Comment: whay are u not using self there , or else any other u had declared ?

Comment: below i am giving the updated code , if it is not satisfied, you paste the code , so that any one can see your code and they may answer your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the self , it automatically detects  previously declared constants or identifiers try this and let me know .

```
cell.textLabel.text = [self.ninjas[indexPath.row] name];
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.ninjas[indexPath.row] thumbnail]]
               placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"50-50.jpg"]];
```

Comment: Thanks for the post, let me check and I'll get to u